# Angularjs ng-repeat get value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting response below that

**myresponse**

```
test: {
    "credit": {
        "1500000": [{
            "date": "2016-07-21",
            "balance": -1528750,
            "category": "Transfer out",
            "narration": "test1",
            "amount": -1500000
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-07-21",
            "balance": -1528750,
            "category": "Transfer out",
            "narration": "test1",
            "amount": -1500000
        }]
    },
```

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered">                        
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Months</th>
        <th class="text-center">Data</th>
        <th class="text-center">Balance</th>
        <th class="text-center">Category</th>
        <th class="text-center">Narration</th>
        <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="my in myctrl.credit">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in my">
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-center">{{val.date}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{val.balance}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{val.category}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{val.narration}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{val.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can get all values but i can't able to get in this **`1500000`** how can i get this

also i want to merge that month row

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i use {{key}} it will show 0 & 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ng-repeats are nested in the wrong order. Should be:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key, val) in myctrl.credit">
 <tr ng-repeat="data in val">
  //data has date, balance, etc
  //key = 150000
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? What's the value of "key" and "val" respectively?

Comment: I want to get 150000 this

Comment: You said its not working. I ask, when you do this I told you, what's the value of key and val? Debug it.

Comment: Ya thanks how i merge that first td if both same value